# Android Directory Errors in xiaomi phones

Tags: android, file, directory

I have a problem like this guys. the anroid application I made is creating a file. I am creating this file with the following code.

```
 file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)+getString(R.string.DosyaCepMap));
```

On other Android devices, the file directory comes as "/ storage / emulated / 0 / ...". but I cannot create a directory in Xiaomi because it is "/ storage / 0 / ...". Does anyone have any idea how I can find a solution on this issue.

Comment: Isnt the difference Android 10/Q?

Comment: Further your statement does not create a file.

Comment: I know it 's create the directory but I didi not  access to directory because of this situation how can resolve thats.

Comment: `Isn't the difference Android 10/Q? `

Comment: `know it 's create the directory ` ? No. It does not.

Comment: no The difference is that Xiami devices create a different format for the application folders and the java code cannot distinguish it.

Comment: I do not understand a word from what you are trying to say.

Comment: Try `file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), getString(R.string.DosyaCepMap));`